# Linq To Sql: Exception "String must be exactly one character long"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Consider a SQL Server table defined with a `varchar(1) NULL` field. It's being used to store a gender character. Some rows have data, some not: either null or blank. Granted the blanks SHOULD be nulls, but consider that blank is a valid value here. I'd much prefer the value to be null.

```
ID    Gender
1      'M'
4      'M'
3      ''
4      'F'
```

An exception is raised when running a Linq To Sql query where the value of `someID` is 3.

```
var emp = (from e in db.Employees
           where e.ID == someID
           select e);
```

**Exception**:

> String must be exactly one character long.

**Question**: What is the cause of this exception? What can be done to prevent or eliminate this problem?

Comment: Why not use Char(1) in SQL Server?

Comment: @Dan - Because it doesn't make sense to change an existing database schema to support a generated file that can be much more easily changed.  The fact that the LINQ to SQL designer uses a Char for varchar(1) is a bug in my opinion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the `Employee` type that was created for you by the LINQ to SQL designer.  Most likely the type for the `Gender` property is `System.Char` (which is the type that the LINQ to SQL designer uses for `varchar(1)`) and should be changed to a `System.String` to properly match your database schema.

The fact that the LINQ to SQL designer interprets a `varchar(1)` as a `System.Char` is foolish considering that this is valid T-SQL:

```
declare @foo varchar(1);
set @foo = '';
```

and this is *invalid* C#:

```
Char foo = '';
```

Since the type of the property that was generated is too restrictive you need to change it to be a `System.String`.

**Note:** *You may want to consider adding some validation inside the setter of the property to throw an exception if the length of the string is greater than one.*

Comment: More information and a great explanation here: http://dotnetslackers.com/XLinq/re-63043_LINQ_Error_String_must_be_exactly_one_character_long.aspx

Comment: ...and if you have a lot of varchar(1) fields, using the update/sync feature in http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/ will automagically correct the mapping for those fields (from char to string).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the blank data like '' doesn't meet the current constraints of the table?  E.g. perhaps the table doesn't permit empty strings (even though there is one in there).

Then, maybe LINQ is applying those constraints for you, or expecting those constraints to be met and complaining that they are not.

If this is what is going on, you might change the constraints/design of the table to allow blank values, or just update all the blank values to NULL (assuming NULLs are allowed)

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs when Linq To SQL Designer tries to auto generate a results class, for holding stored procedure results. Copy the auto generated class into your own new class file (use same name) and make changes there. Each time you update your DataContext it will just be a case of deleting the auto generated class. Not an ideal solution but a workaround for 2008.